# Laravel : Why my "notification" data from database not showing up?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

so, i got these code from controllers, Routes, and inside the app.blade.view:
controllers :

```
public function showNotif(){        
  $dataNotif= Notification::get();
  // dd($dataNotif);
  return view('/',compact('dataNotif'));
}
```

Routes :

```
Route::get('/','homeController@showNotif');
```

and inside app.blade.view i got these codes inside clickable bell icons that shows notifications:

```
@if(isset($dataNotif))
  @foreach($dataNotif as $dn)
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">                  
       <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
          <p>{{$dn->notifikasi}}</p>
       </div>
    </a>           
  @endforeach          
@else  
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">                  
     <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
         <p>No Notifications!</p>
     </div>
  </a>
@endif
```

when i was trying just to use the foreach method inside the app.blade.view, but it always showing the "undefined variable" on $dataNotif error, but when i using the isset first, there's no data shows up, it should be 2 notifications data shows up when i was opening the main website...

so, is there any missconception or minor mistakes that i made?

thanks for answering..

Comment: what did you get for `dd($dataNotif);`?

Answer (score -1):

Can help if we don't know what your Notification class looks like, and last I checked the data in a notification is accessed via `$notification->data['notifikasi']` assuming your notification class looked like this:

```
/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'notifikasi' => 'lorem ipsum'
    ];
}
```

Comment: oh, a lil bit info, i'm not using any of the "notification" method on the laravel, i just simply making migration, and model to have a simple notification... so i'm affraid i'm not that undestand on this class tho...

Comment: If that is the case try using `all()` instead of `get()`.

Answer (score -2):

If a notification supports being stored in a database table, you should define a `toDatabase` method on the notification class. This method will receive a `$notifiable` entity and should return a plain PHP array. The returned array will be encoded as JSON and stored in the `data` column of your `notifications` table. Let's take a look at an example `toDatabase` method:

```
/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'invoice_id' => $this->invoice->id,
        'amount' => $this->invoice->amount,
    ];
}
```

#### Accessing The Notifications

Once notifications are stored in the database, you need a convenient way to access them from your notifiable entities. The `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait, which is included on Laravel's default `App\User` model, includes a `notifications` Eloquent relationship that returns the notifications for the entity. To fetch notifications, you may access this method like any other Eloquent relationship. By default, notifications will be sorted by the `created_at` timestamp:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {
    echo $notification->type;
}
```